# Onboard soundcard not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

I think Something happened to on board sound card.

No sound played when I connect any speakers/hedphones to backpanel jack or to front jack.

What I hear is static sound even if nothing is playing!

As soon as windows 10 loads I am hearing the static sound.

Everything was working fine form the day I bought my PC.

Tried to reinstall drivers, didn't help.

How can I verify that the  problem is with motherboard?

Comment: How loud is the static sound? The first thing I would try is some different speakers, also. It seems more likely that your speakers would go out than your on-board sound card. I've never had an on-board sound card fail on me.

Comment: tried different, when i connect speakers to other audio device no static sound.

Comment: Try this: Press Win+R (or just open the "Run..." box from the start menu) and type `dxdiag`. Click yes on the dialog box that pops up. There should be one or more "Sound" tabs, find the one for your internal sound card. If there's anything under "Notes" (besides "No problems found.") then copy / paste the entire "Notes" box as a comment or add it to your question.

Comment: all of them no Problems found.

Is there a way to check sound card  outside windows? Is there any bootable sound tool? Or maybe I need  to install some linux?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any testing software that will test for hardware issues - normally they just play various sounds and you're supposed to see if you hear them or not. Obviously you've already determined that you can't so that's not useful. You might try booting into a live CD of Ubuntu or some other linux distro and trying to play some audio. This would at least rule out a configuration issue in Windows.

Comment: Same happens in Ubuntu... will check tomorrow if I still have warranty. If not the only option is to buy external sound card?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like the card is fried. You could replace the entire motherboard but it would definitely be easier to just get a different sound card. They're real cheap nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The external sound card is a USB, PCI or PCI-1 interface. There is no way to detect the sound card of the motherboard. Try to update the BIOS if we can, if it does not work, try to replace the motherboard if you still have warranty.